# Using AJAX to create an Object which then appears in dropdown box

Tags: ajax, django, view

Hi I've run into a problem where I am trying to make it so when a button is clicked an object can be made. I can't get it to work as for some reason it will not validate, however if I change input type to submit it works fine.

But the problem is when I use it as submit the page redirects which defeats the purpose of using AJAX.

I can't seem to find a good tutorial for what I'd like to do, any help or links would really be appreciated!

**Models**

```
class MemberRole(models.Model,get_fields):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

**Form**

```
class MemberRoleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MemberRole
```

**Views**
This view builds the form for the memberrole model

```
def add_member(request):
    model_url = 'member-add'
    rform = MemberRoleForm(instance=MemberRole())
    return render_to_response('create_model.html', {'role_form': rform,'model_url': model_url,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This ajax called view

```
@require_POST
def ajax(request):
    data = request.POST.get("rolename","")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rform = MemberRoleForm(request.POST, instance=MemberRole())
        if rform.is_valid():
            new_role = rform.save()
            new_role.name = data
            return HttpResponse("SuccessFully Saved")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Error in saving")
```

**Template**

```
    <div id="addRoleOnMemberForm">
        <form id = "addrole" onsubmit= "return false;" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in role_form %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }} //#id_name is in here
        {% endfor %}
        <input id="addrolebutton" type="button" onclick = "createit()" value="Add New Role"/>
    </div>
    {% for x in role_list %}

    <div>
        <p> This shows a role was made </p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    function createit(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"ajax",
dataType:"json",
async: true,
data: {
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
rolename: $('#id_name').val()
},

});
}
</script>
```

Comment: For sending forms in js I always use [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to get it to work. :)

I have an add_member view which allows the creation of a memberrole object if it is not available in the member.role dropdown field. The memberrole object on creation will be added without a page reload to the dropdown field so it can be selected immediatly.

I'm not entirely sure if this would be the correct way of coding it, I've included all the source and hopefully it helps someone like me. Comments would be appreciated!

**Models**

```
class MemberRole(models.Model,get_fields):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

class Member(models.Model,get_fields):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    role = models.ForeignKey(MemberRole, null = True, blank = True)
```

**Forms**

```
class MemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Member
```

**Script**

```
<script>
        function createit(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"addrole",
                    dataType:"json",
                    async: true,
                    data: {
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                        rolename: $('#role_name').val()
                    },
                    success: function (json,rolename){
                        $('#output').html(json.message); // Prints a message to say that the MemberRole object was created
                        $('#roleExistsMemberForm').load(document.URL + ' #roleExistsMemberForm'); //Refreshes the dropdown box so that the newly created MemberRole can be selected
                    }
                });
            }
    </script>
```

**Views**

```
def add_role(request):
    model_url = 'role-add'
    new_role = request.POST.get("rolename","")
    role_list = MemberRole.objects.all()
    response_data= {}

    if new_role:
        x = MemberRole()
        x.name = new_role
        x.save()
        response_data['message'] = new_role + " was created"
    else:
        response_data['message'] = 'Nothing created'

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type="application/json")

def add_member(request):
    model_url = 'member-add'

    if request.method == "POST":
        mform = MemberForm(request.POST, instance=Member())
        if mform.is_valid():
        new_member = mform.save(commit=False)
        new_member.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('members')
    else:
        mform = MemberForm(instance=Member())
    return render_to_response('create_model.html', {'member_form': mform, 'model_url': model_url,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**create_model.html**

```
{% for field in member_form %}
{% if field.label == 'Role' %}
<div id="roleExistsMemberForm">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
        <div id="addRoleOnMemberForm">
        <form onsubmit="return false;">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input id= "role_name" type="text"/>
        <input id="addrolebut" type="button" onclick = "createit()" value="Add New Role"/>
    </div>
    <div id="output">
    <p>Nothing here</p>
</div>
```